# Dynamically created ID change in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello All,

I am using telerik treeview in my ASP.NET web application.I have two table and create table dynamically from those table with below query:

```
DECLARE @maxParent INT;
        SELECT @maxParent = MAX(folderID)
        FROM folder;

        ;WITH DATA AS
        (
            SELECT folderID AS ID, SortOrder AS SortOrder, NULL AS ParentId, Name as Text,0 as MasterChartEntryId
            FROM table1 where IsEnabled=1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT @maxParent + folderID , SortOrder AS SortOrder,  folderID, Text,MasterChartEntryId
            FROM table2 where IsEnabled=1
        )
        SELECT * FROM DATA  
        ORDER BY SortOrder ASC
```

I want to create dynamically unique id which done by this query but when added new record id is changed.I don't want to change the id if new record inserted.
Any one help for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you could use folderID as an ID but, because you generate @maxParent + folderID after the union your ID will deppen on the  @maxParent = MAX(folderID).

Simply change @maxParent to a static big number like @maxParent= 1000000000 and your problem will be solved for a short time.

If you want to have a beter solution then you need a shared ID among table1 and table2.